# Javascript onclick global event handlers fires before page is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I have a global event handler for an image.

`document.getElementById("post_image").onclick = photoEnlarge;`

The above returns **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null** since the image with the ID `post_image` is being loaded via `window.onload` and `createElement("img")`

What can I do to make the above work without the TypeError?

and

What is the proper use of global event handlers? (I directly put them before the closing body tag along with the other js. Is that wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you add the handler after you create the element. If you are adding the element in the onload handler, just apply the onclick handler in the same block.